# Can I run(virtualize) Multiple Mac OS on Mac Servers or Mac computers?

Tags: mac

Can I run (virtualize) Multiple Mac OS X versions on a Mac Server or a Mac computer?

If the answer is yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Please note that if you are doing this on a Mac OS X version other than Mac OS X Server, it violates the Mac OS X EULA.

Answer (score 1):

[Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) can also run OS X server as a guest on a Mac host.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtualbox](http://hackaday.com/2010/05/03/virtualbox-beta-runs-mac-os-x/) has been able to run OS X as a guest on macs for the last year or so - and its apparently a matter of just installing as per usual. I seem to recall that vmware had a solution as well, but i'm not certain about that.